# Interactive webpage with JS editor

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, three.js

I want to create a webpage that has a working code underneath it but interactively parts can be changed.

Example:

On left side i have canvas. On canvas i have some JS code running with THREEJS to show me something. On the right i have the editor. Inside the editor there is the current function used to show something on the left side. I want to be able to manipulate the code on the right, and when i press play or execute or something the visualization on the left will change.

So if i had white canvas with a blue dot on the left. And on the right there is currently empty function, nothing happens. But now if i write in like something like "dx += Math.sin(time)" and press execute the dot now starts moving.

Edit

How can i achieve something like this? I read about using eval but can eval access JS variables outside the function? Or can i give it some parameters ?

Comment: You didn't ask a question.

Comment: I think he is looking for an eval loop, he wants to enter code on one side to sort-of execute on the other. But yes, you didn't _really_ ask a question. For this kind of sort-of-thing, maybe a library like Ractify does the trick for you?

Comment: `eval` is quite dangerous. Is it important that you can edit code in such a fashion or can you just use the tried and tested save-and-reload? If you go for a full eval there are ways to limit access to variables, but you should never really allow users to program in your code without really knowing what you are doing...

Comment: @somethinghere this is for school work, gona use it for examples and stuff. It is meant to be to easily mess around within the given function. The full scope will be like 3-4 function where they anything can be done within the scope of the functions.